# Serializing to Unicode text file in MFC - wrong file header

Tags: c++, serialization, unicode, mfc, byte-order-mark

I am trying to serialize a list of objects.Objects themselves contain only CString members. The serialization is done to a text file in order to create human-readable log file. 
The issue is that in order to write Unicode strings, the file is needed to be have BOM(byte order mark) for a Unicode encoding.

```
FILE *fStream = NULL;

VERIFY( _tfopen_s( &fStream, _T( "D:\\Test.txt" ), _T( "wt,ccs=UNICODE" ) ) == 0 );

CStdioFile theFile;

theFile.m_pStream = fStream;

CArchive archive( &theFile, CArchive::store );

ListContainingObject.Serialize( archive );
```

In `Serialize()` I am trying to write the number of the elements so  `CArchive::WriteCount()` is called with the size of the list. 
This messes up the BOM and if the file is opened in Notepad for example, 
`-` sign is showed at the beggining of the file.

In HEX viewer the file header looks like this: `ff fe 06 00`.
I understand that 06 is the capacity of the list that i have written.I also understand that `-` has probably the ASCII value of `ff fe 06 00` The question is:

Is there any way in which i can write down an integer to the beginning of the file and not mess it up with the byte order mark so no symbol is shown in text editors?

Comment: `ff fe` is the UTF-16 BOM. `-` has the ASCII value `2d`. If you want to (ab)use a [CArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caz3zy5s.aspx) to store human readable text, you will have to convert everything to text first, and call `operator <<(wchar_t)` for each code unit. But really, `CArchive` is meant for compound binary data. Using it for anything else makes things needlessly complex. If you want to store human readable text, use a C++ filestream instead.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, it's all going to be messed up.  If you serialize CString objects, they are also going to write length counts as is the list.

If all you have is a list of strings, then convert the count to a string usingw wsprintf() or CString::Format()...  Write the count as a string  and terminate with a newline ("\n").  Write all the remaining strings as strings terminated with a newline character.  If your strings have newlines in them, well, you are going to have to escape it somehow.  You could put your data in some XML format.  You have lots of choices.

Comment: I was thinking of a workaround in which in the beginning of the file i write a string, which will contain the list count, for example `ListCapacity : 50` and on load i parse the integer, but i wanted to see if there is another "cleaner" case.

Comment: Depending on what you use as a delimiter between objects/records/strings, it might not even be necessary to write a count at all.  Every time you come across the delimiter, append the object to the end of the list and begin processing the next new object/record/string.